# Ultra-fast database access for web applications - SQL or NoSQL, Interpreted PHP or Compiled C?

Tags: php, sql, c, database, apache

I'm currently building a web application that needs to access a (really) big database of strings and compare them to a given 'request string' - This has to be done over and over again using different comparison methods (number of identical words, order of words...) and should be scalable and, more important, fast.

I thought about about implementing the comparison method itself in **C**, because it's obviously much faster than interpreted, though more 'webby' languages like PHP.
This brought me to three questions:

1) How am I supposed to **'connect' the C application to the web server** (currently Apache)? I thought about the usual CGI-way, but because of its need to create one new process per request it would be less scalable and fast - at least that's what I read about it.

2) Which **database technology** is best to use with C for this use-case?

3) Last but not least, do you think it's **worth the struggle** or would it be enough to go the usual way by building a PHP-Script that connects to a MySQL database - how big is the **speed difference**?

Thanks in advance, 
David

Comment: Could you give us some concrete(ish) numbers about what you mean by "a (really) big database of strings"? And also how many different search permutations need to be run against each query-string?

Comment: Certainly a few million sentence-long strings, probably tens-of-millions.

Comment: Consider keeping the entire list of strings in memory (about 1 gigabyte if my math is accurate) and foregoing a database except to persist the list when the server is down.  You don't define "fast", but if speed is at issue, and various complex string comparisons are needed, a disk-based database probably won't cut it.

Comment: Too many questions with too many answers. You'll need to turn this into multiple questions which are focused.

Comment: You've asked three separate questions, at least two of which (2 and 3) are asking for discussion and opinion and are inappropriate for StackOverflow. (The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions those types of question as being a poor fit for this format.) You should restrict your posts to 1 question per post, so that a single answer can be chosen as correct. With three questions in the same post, it's conceivable that three people could each answer a different one - in that case, how could you choose which one to accept as correct?

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your feedback and will try to ask more focused in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Bad application architecture, bad database design and bad code will *always* run inefficiently slow won't scalable.

If you get that out of the way most "very high demand" purposes can be served with any of the interpreted languages - remember they're optimized at what they do (wasteful with memory for example but usually pretty fast even for high demand use).

### Having said that we get to the real answer:

In database design there is no perfect approach for all use-cases. You may need to structure your database in one way to achieve the best reading speed, and in another to achieve the best writing speed, and yet another to achieve the best flexibility (but sacrificing both read and write speed). A section may need high read speed another may need high write speed and yet another may need high flexibility.

Think of the way you designed the database and ask yourself "do i need to connect to the database 300 times in a session to gather all of the data or could I write one big statement that can read it all at once" if this is not easily achievable think if you can write an SQL stored procedure that can do that if you come up empty again think if you could change the structure (sacrificing flexibility for example) to allow for a one-liner read or a stored procedure read.

In any case many-many connections from PHP to MySQL sending 1 query means you're spending a hefty amount of time waiting for PHP to connect to the MySQL server over the network (even if it's local) and for MySQL to process the request and supply an answer etc. and so on and so forth. If you can either batch-generate all of the statements you intend to send into one string that's great, if not if you can group them in smaller batches that's OK as well.

### If all of the above is unacceptable or if you really have a knack for writing a C script today (laudable intent by all means):

You should consider writing a C MySQL module defining some UDF - user defined functions. They can have access to row-level data at the moment MySQL is reading it, and they can process for output aggregate and all that jazz.

Writing an apache module or a PHP module will deliver data in much the same format as the MySQL module but the processing won't be running inside the MySQL server it will be requesting data from MySQL, processing it and requesting more data.

Answer (score 0):

Apache-2.4.x has mod_dbd, which can talk to various database back-ends (using precompiled queries for speed) straight out of Apache config-files. This can be used in, for example, [mod_rewrite's rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to alter incoming requests depending on results of the queries.

In other words, depending on the details of your application, you may be able to avoid coding altogether.

If you do have to write code, however, I'd suggest you first implement the prototype in a language you know best. There is a good chance, it will be "fast enough" -- or that the bulk of the time spent per request will be on the database side making the choice of the language irrelevant.

Connecting to a database back-end from C is easy -- each database vendor has (at least one) client-library implementation for C-programs.

If your app does not require multiple HTTP-servers to talk to the same (single) database, then your best DB would be a local one: SleepyCat's (now Oracle's) "db", gdbm, or SQLite3.

Also, if the updates (changes to the database) are infrequent, you can use flat-files and build the database in memory... This will limit the database's maximum size, but will be the fastest and allow you avoid handling (re)connections, etc.

EDIT: memcache is an external database -- whether it is running on the same system or a remote one, you have to *connect* to it, *talk* to it, and *copy* data from its memory into yours. If database-changes aren't frequent, you are better off keeping stuff in your own memory and using it straight from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll work myself through the solutions you mentioned. Using precompiled queries without using a full programming language at  all looks pretty interesting.

Comment: For in-memory DB's with persistent storage Redis may fit the bill as well. It's kind-of like Memcached - an "in-memory" key-value storage cache but it allows you to specify some advanced datatypes as values (arrays pointing to other Redis stored values and the like). It keeps a binary log in case you reboot the server you don't need to do a cache warming, it wasn't designed to read/write from the disk.

Comment: "At least one client library" is pretty much an understatement. All fast running "high performance", "mission critical" pieces of software were written in C sometimes with a pinch of Assembler here and there. And therefore all of their clients are initially written in C. PHP's MySQL client is just a wrapper over the C client.

Comment: Memcached's strongpoint is the fact that you can use a pool of servers each allocating a little or a lot of memory. when you save something you save into the pool and retrieve  it from the pool. like this you can achieve a memory pool larger than any single machine could have.